# Download a file without URL

Tags: casperjs

I'm updating some old CasperJS code that downloads a CSV report. The web interface recently changed. The old version had a link tag I could grab and then use `casper.download()` to retrieve the file.

However, the new version appears to be an Angular app and the download button triggers a `handleDownload()` function that does something under the hood, which results in a popup dialog in my browser.

Is there some way to intercept this dialog or otherwise extract the URL from the actual file?

Comment: Did you try looking at what requests are being made when you download the file?

Comment: That's a good idea. Strangely I'm not seeing the file transfer in the network tab on chrome. I can see some API requests, but the file itself is being downloaded through some other means. I deduced that from the fact the requests total 6k according to chrome devtools and the file itself is 30k

Comment: Can you link the website? I am sure it's in the requests somewhere.

Comment: It's behind a login unfortunately. Surely there are only so many places in devtools I can look to find where the actual transfer is taking place?

Comment: Under the network tab like you have been looking is correct. Sometimes the requests can be confusing, but it has to be in there somewhere.

Comment: That's what I thought. The original page load is 800k+. I'm now wondering if they're actually sending all the data to the client regardless and then doing the report generation in the browser.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure. Unfortunately, it is really hard to help you without being able to see the site. Best of luck!

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the suggestions anyway

Comment: The network tab in Firefox shows me the actual URL of the download. No idea what chrome is doing

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

- You can see what URL is requested (F12 > Network in Chrome).  You could then try to deduce the URL.
- Look at what handleDownload does - the logic should be available to
  you.  You may be able to pull data there.

Hard to help without seeing the code.

Comment: See my comment above for checking the URL. I don't see the csv request itself showing up. Is there another place in devtools other than the network tab to see file transfers? As for looking at the source, that was the first thing I tried but it's minified and even after letting chrome pretty print it I haven't been able to untangle the logic yet.

Comment: Try the Sources tab.